# OS X Tiger Won't Detect Logitech Harmony 670 Universal Remote

Tags: usb, remote-control, osx-tiger, logitech-universal-remote

I have a Logitech Harmony 670 universal remote and a Macbook running OS X 10.5 Tiger. I've downloaded the Harmony software (v 7.6.0.8), but it won't detect the remote when I plug it in via USB (however the remote is getting power, as it's operating without batteries).

Logitech's website/troubleshooter is of no help. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: Have you tried installing batteries to see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it on 2 other Windows boxes and had no luck, so it appears to be a hardware problem. Logitech support agrees but they're not replacing it as it's out of warranty. :-\